# moment.js diff incorrect hours when at the end of the month

Tags: momentjs

I have a start date and time that I'm checking against an end date and time. Everything appears to work fine when checking two dates within a certain month, but if I go from the end of one month to the beginning of another, I get weird results.

If I have a Start Date and time of:

```
//08/31/2014 08:00AM
var AugEnd = moment([2014, 08, 31, 08, 00]);
```

And an End Date and time of:

```
//09/01/2014 08:00AM
var SeptStart = moment([2014, 09, 01, 08, 00]);
```

I Should get a result of 24, but I'm given 0 instead

```
var Time1 = SeptStart.diff(AugEnd, 'hours', true);
```

This appears to happen at the end of most months with the exception of 07/31 - 08/01 and 12/31 - 01/01.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65a83ckz/4/

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?
(Using moment.min.js, version 2.8.2)

Solution thanks to Mudaser Ali:

The Months start at 0 so,

```
January = 0
February = 01
March = 02
April = 03
May = 04
June = 05
July = 06
Aug = 07
Sept = 08
Oct = 09 
Nov = 10
Dec = 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your date is inValid

```
var SeptStart = moment([2014, 08, 31, 08, 00]);
```

it is date of september and because in js month start from 0 so 8 = september and month of september has 30 days not 31 days so it should be

```
var SeptStart = moment([2014, 08, 30, 08, 00]);
```

so after change it you will get the correct result

```
var SeptEnd = moment([2014, 09, 01, 08, 00]); //it is correct date
```

and

```
var SeptTime = SeptEnd.diff(SeptStart, 'hours', true); //equals to 24 hrs
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/*smakii*/qs1b4298/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/_smakii_/qs1b4298/1/)

Comment: Ok! So January actually starts at 0. I understand that JS usually starts at 0, but just funny that the months start this way. I'm guessing the dates start at 1. Interesting